# linking to network share with safari

Tags: html, safari

I am trying to dynamically generate links to files on a network share that will work in both IE and safari.  In IE, doing `href=\\networksharename\foldername\filename` works fine, and we thought this worked fine on safari in our initial testing, but our safari users are reporting page cannot be displayed.  These are pdf files.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Windows Safari or Mac Safari? I imagine the answer might be significantly different.

Answer (score 1):

First, you should replace the backslash (\) with slash (/). A full URL may also be helpfull (something like smb://server/shared-folder/...), but i do not know what share you have.

Answer (score 0):

Are the shares on a DFS?  MacOS does not have DFS support.